# Is seam page action normally executed as an initial request or on a postback?

Tags: java, seam

I implemented some page action on one of my view..it appears that when i load or access the page/view..
the method on my component get executed every time..IS this normal behavior in seam or i am missing something...

---

I already solved my problem..What i am trying to accomplish is a initial request when a page is requested either by typing the page URL of the page in the address bar or from a result of a bookmark.
In SEAM it is achieved via they call page action.You declare page action in component descriptor or the component.xml...

```
<page view-id="/list.xhtml">
    <action execute="#{conpoentName.componentMethod}" on-postback="false"/>
```

If the attribute on-postback is not stated..what happen is a continues call to component method when i tried to access the page..it's like having a infinite call..

Anybody knows what is happening in the background?..Its seams related to postback..

Comment: Hello and welcome on stackOverflow. Could you please provide us with more informations, like the framework you are using (if you are using one) or some code?

Comment: Oh i am really sorry..i am using SEAM framework..actually i already solved the problem..using is-postback="false"..I dont know what really happens in the background so i don't know why it happens..I'm trying to figure that out..:)

Comment: Could you could add your solution as an answer and update your question with more information please :)

Comment: ... if you'd answered yourself *in an explicit answer* and flag it as *answered*, other would see that the question is complete... plus you might earn some credentials if you get upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is normal behavior.  Take a look at [Seam FAQ JSF Postback](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/HowDoAPreventAnPageActionFromExecutingOnPostback)
You want to perform an action when a page is initially loaded, if you don't want that action executed on repeated access you use the Postback attribute, or put some logic in the execute method to prevent it.